# TCL calculate mapping

Tags: tcl

I have a list contain mapping as below

```
# {from, to, count}
{{XD} PD 2}
{{XB} PB 4}
{{XA0, XA1} PA 4}
```

How can I create the mapping from [XD, XB, XA0, XA1] and to [PD, PB, PA] using TCL

```
Expected

# XD   XB   XA0  XA1
{{PD0  PB0  PA0  PA1}
{ PD0  PB0  PA2  PA3}

{ PD0  PB1  PA0  PA1}
{ PD0  PB1  PA2  PA3}

{ PD0  PB2  PA0  PA1}
{ PD0  PB2  PA2  PA3}

{ PD0  PB3  PA0  PA1}
{ PD0  PB3  PA2  PA3}


{ PD1  PB0  PA0  PA1}
{ PD1  PB0  PA2  PA3}
....}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Setting up XA1 as a separate mapping entry will make your life easier.

Comment: That's a non-trivial transformation precisely because of the way the values from a single sequence counter are used in multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular problem is really best handled recursively. In particular, generating the count for a particular counter then leads to calling back in to handle the next counter in the chain. A bit of care is required to piece together the results in the right order (there's a few ways to do it) but the one below is nice because it generates the data as a list of lists, allowing it to be processed further or pretty-printed as you choose.

Note the use of a defaulted argument to start the recursion off. It's possible to do without by using a wrapper procedure, but that's a refinement.

```
proc genseq {definition {current {}}} {
    # Get the next part of the definition
    lassign [lindex $definition 0] columns prefix limit
    set definition [lrange $definition 1 end]

    set result {}
    for {set i 0} {$i < $limit} {} {
        # Handle the appending of bits relating to the counter at the current level
        set cur $current
        foreach c $columns {
            lappend cur "$prefix$i"
            incr i
        }

        # If we have more definition to process, recursive call. Otherwise just accumulate
        if {[llength $definition] > 0} {
            lappend result {*}[genseq $definition $cur]
        } else {
            lappend result $cur
        }
    }
    return $result
}
```

Let's test it out:

```
set seqinfo {
    {{XD} PD 2}
    {{XB} PB 4}
    {{XA0 XA1} PA 4}
}

# A bit of trickery to get approximately the right output format
puts \{\{[join [genseq $seqinfo] "\}\n\{"]\}\}
```

Produces this output.

```
{{PD0 PB0 PA0 PA1}
{PD0 PB0 PA2 PA3}
{PD0 PB1 PA0 PA1}
{PD0 PB1 PA2 PA3}
{PD0 PB2 PA0 PA1}
{PD0 PB2 PA2 PA3}
{PD0 PB3 PA0 PA1}
{PD0 PB3 PA2 PA3}
{PD1 PB0 PA0 PA1}
{PD1 PB0 PA2 PA3}
{PD1 PB1 PA0 PA1}
{PD1 PB1 PA2 PA3}
{PD1 PB2 PA0 PA1}
{PD1 PB2 PA2 PA3}
{PD1 PB3 PA0 PA1}
{PD1 PB3 PA2 PA3}}
```

I'll leave putting in the headers and extra space rows as an exercise. (Also, Tcl doesn't separate lists with commas; indeed, commas are ordinary characters with very little special about them outside of expressions.)

Comment: Hmm...I probably would have just had a single loop and a counter per sequence item.   Not as elegant, and the stop condition would be messy.

Answer (score 1):

Well I looked at the desired output and thought it looked suspiciously like the Cartesian product of a set of relation values. So, in the spirit of killing flies with a sledge hammer, you can use the TclRAL (http://chiselapp.com/user/mangoa01/repository/tclral/index), a relational algebra extension to Tcl, and do it with relations:

```
 package require ral

 # The original format of the spec.
 set mapspec {
    {XD PD 2}
    {XB PB 4}
    {{XA0 XA1} PA 4}
  }
# Way too much code required to convert from
# the original data to a set of relation values.
foreach spec $mapspec {
    lassign $spec attrs body count
    set heading [list]
    foreach attr $attrs {
        lappend heading $attr string
    }
    set tuples [list]
    for {set i 0} {$i < $count} {} {
        set tuple [list]
        foreach attr $attrs {
            lappend tuple $attr $body$i
            incr i ; # assume count % [llength $attrs] == 0
            # puts "tuple = $tuple"
        }
        lappend tuples $tuple
        # puts "tuples = $tuples"
    }
    set rel [ral relation create $heading {*}$tuples]
    # puts [ral relformat $rel rel]
    lappend rels $rel
}

# The "real work" is a one liner.
set prod [ral relation times {*}$rels]
# Print the result as a table.
puts [ral relformat $prod "Mapping as a relation value"]
```

Running this gives:

```
+------+------+------+------+
|XD    |XB    |XA0   |XA1   |
|string|string|string|string|
+------+------+------+------+
|PD0   |PB0   |PA0   |PA1   |
|PD0   |PB0   |PA2   |PA3   |
|PD0   |PB1   |PA0   |PA1   |
|PD0   |PB1   |PA2   |PA3   |
|PD0   |PB2   |PA0   |PA1   |
|PD0   |PB2   |PA2   |PA3   |
|PD0   |PB3   |PA0   |PA1   |
|PD0   |PB3   |PA2   |PA3   |
|PD1   |PB0   |PA0   |PA1   |
|PD1   |PB0   |PA2   |PA3   |
|PD1   |PB1   |PA0   |PA1   |
|PD1   |PB1   |PA2   |PA3   |
|PD1   |PB2   |PA0   |PA1   |
|PD1   |PB2   |PA2   |PA3   |
|PD1   |PB3   |PA0   |PA1   |
|PD1   |PB3   |PA2   |PA3   |
+------+------+------+------+
Mapping as a relation value
---------------------------
```

All of this is not worthwhile and intended in a playful spirit. Unless, that is, you need to manipulate further the result. Then the relational operators can do some interesting transformations.